# Need to calculate sum in big query using window function?

Tags: google-bigquery

Below is the example data for which I need to calculate the sum of qty and fcst based on start and end date based on coverage days.

I need to calculate sum of qty and fcst for an item based on start and end date and add a new column DOS which is sum(qty)/sum(fcst) * coverage days
[image]

[image]

I am not sure if I should be using window function or some other function to achieve this. Having said that I am not able to achieve this using window function. Need inputs/help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple sum and group by function to achieve what you want

```
SELECT sum(qty) as sum_of_qty, sum(fcst) as sum_of_fcst, sum(qty)/sum(fcst)*coverage_days as DoS FROM table group by item,start_date,end_date,coverage_days;
```